# Получение размеров компонентов

Tags: android

У компонента указан размер – wrap_content;
Помогите получить числовой размер через ViewGroup.LayoutParams в dp, потому что у самого пока не получается – если брать у него один из параметров, то он берется так же как wrap_content.

Comment: Насколько я знаю - узнать размер в пикселях невозможно через ViewGroup.LayoutParams, если используется `wrap_content`, т.к. все методы, определяющие конкретный размер выполнятся только в процессе отрисовки. Вроде как вам надо для получение размера использовать специальный асинхронный колбэк. Посмотрите тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43633598/3212712

Comment: перегружайте onWindowFocusChanged и смотрите там